# Expo React native crash (child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

i'm using multiple Dependencies in Expo RN app, the project has been successfully done year ago and now when i try to build and run it again, i'm getting this error: `child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function`.

i've tried cleaning and reinstall node_modules also checked expo community and no solution so far.

Detailed log issue:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle. node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/gesture.ts: /Users/ilies/Desktop/LinkAll/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/gesture.ts: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function
```

and this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.4",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.1.0",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.5",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.0",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.13",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.13",
"big-integer": "^1.6.51",
"deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
"expo": "~47.0.12",
"expo-credit-card": "^0.0.5",
"expo-google-app-auth": "^10.0.0",
"expo-google-sign-in": "^11.0.0",
"expo-intent-launcher": "^10.3.1",
"expo-linear-gradient": "^12.0.1",
"expo-modules-core": "^1.1.1",
"expo-notifications": "^0.17.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "^0.17.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
"expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
"firebase": "^9.17.1",
"i": "^0.3.7",
"lottie-react-native": "^5.1.5",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"moment-range": "^4.0.2",
"patch-package": "^6.5.1",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.43.1",
"react-html-email": "^3.0.0",
"react-moment": "^1.1.3",
"react-native": "^0.70.5",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1293.0",
"react-native-credit-card": "^0.1.9",
"react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
"react-native-draggable-calendar": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-interactable": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
"react-native-map-link": "^2.10.2",
"react-native-maps": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
"react-native-sendgrid": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-web": "^0.18.12",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"rn-credit-card": "^1.0.4",
"text-encoding": "^0.7.0"},

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9" }
```

Comment: Could you solve this ? If so, how?

Comment: Not yet still facing same issue since the past month, i'll keep you updated in case i found a solution for this case

Comment: I've posted a bug report in github repository, etc. w/o luck. It's a pita

Answer (score -1):

Switching to `yarn` was for me the only way to solve this issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34739749)